# Frobenius theorem method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-forms

**Question**: Let $A(z)$ be smooth with nonvanishing derivative $A'(z)$, and consider the system with first-order PDE's,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial K}{\partial x}(x,y)\frac{1}{A'(u)}$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial K}{\partial y}(x,y)\frac{1}{A'(u)}$$

satisfying the initial data $u(x_0,y_0)=u_0$

Useing Frobenius theorem, show that a solution $u(x,y)$ exists, and find the algebraic equation that $u(x,y)$ satisfies

**Answer**:(Given as a hint) $A(u)-A(u_0)=K(x,y)-K(x_0,y_0)$

**My attempt**: I have found the $\mathbb{X}$ and $\mathbb{Y}$ to be:

$$\mathbb{X}=(1,0,\frac{\partial K}{\partial x}(x,y)\frac{1}{A'(z)})$$ and

$$\mathbb{Y}=(0,1,\frac{\partial K}{\partial y}(x,y)\frac{1}{A'(z)})$$

Computing $[\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}]$ I got the result $0$, so have the necessary condition for solution for differential equation and initial conditions to exist.

**Point of contention**: When I compute the flow $\Psi_s$ for $\mathbb{Y}$, I run into a problem.

We have: $x'=0,y'=1,z'=\frac{\partial K}{\partial y}(x,y)\frac{1}{A'(z)},x(0)=x_0,y(0)=y_0,z(0)=u_0$ giving:

$$x(s)=x_0,y(s)=s+y_0,z(s):\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial K}{\partial y}(x,y)\frac{1}{A'(z)}\Leftrightarrow\int_{u_0}^uA'(z)dz=\int_0^s\frac{\partial K}{\partial y}(x,y)ds\Leftrightarrow A(z)-A(u_0)=\frac{\partial K}{\partial y}(x,y)s$$

Where do I go from here, how do I obtain a function for $z(s)$?

Did I do this integral correctly? I am not sure what $A'(z)$ is differentiated with respect to $z$ or not.

I appear to be close to the answer and I feel that after I overcome this small obstacle I will be fine.

**Progress**: Multiplying by $A'(u)$ to simplify I get

$$\frac{\partial A(u)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial k(x,y)}{\partial x}$$ $$\frac{\partial A(u)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial k(x,y)}{\partial y}$$ with initial data $u(x_0,y_0)=u_0$

I compute the vector fields as follows: $\mathbb{X}=(1,0,\frac{\partial k(x,y)}{\partial x})$ and $\mathbb{Y}=(0,1,\frac{\partial k(x,y)}{\partial y})$ Calculating $[\mathbb{X},\mathbb{Y}]$ I get the result $0$ so the necessary condition is satisfied and the solution for $u(x,y)$ exists.

I now need to compute $(\Phi_x\circ\Psi_y)(x_0,y_0,z_0)$

For $\Psi_s$ the flow of vector field $\mathbb{Y}$:

We have: $x'=0,y'=1,z'=\frac{\partial K}{\partial y}(x,y),x(0)=x_0,y(0)=y_0,z(0)=u_0$

giving:

$$x(s)=x_0,y(s)=s+y_0,z(s):\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial K(x,y)}{\partial y}$$

How do I continue from here, seem further away from the answer than I previously was, don't know how to deal with this simplification.

Comment: This problems simplifies if you multiply by $A'(u)$ and noting that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} A'(u) = \frac{\partial A(u)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} A'(u) = \frac{\partial A(u)}{\partial y}$.

Comment: Where do you multiply by $A'(u)$? At the beginning? Also, I am unsure how $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}A'(u)=\frac{\partial A(u)}{\partial x}$? Surely $A'(u)$ is the differential of $A(u)$ with respect to $u$?

Comment: Sorry, I see that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}A'(u)=\frac{\partial A(u)}{\partial x}$ from the chain rule

Comment: How do you know that $A'(u)$ was with respect to $x$ and not anything else

Comment: Because you have written so. It says $A'(z)$ is the normal derivative of the $A(z)$ function. $A'(u)$ is the derivative of the $A$ function evaluated at $z=u$. By the chain rule we therefore get $\frac{dA(u)}{dx} = \left(\frac{dA(z)}{dz}\right)_{z=u}\frac{du}{dx} \equiv A'(u) \frac{du}{dz}$ and likewise for $dA/dy$.

Comment: @Dan $\Phi_x(s) = (x_0 + s, y_0, z_0 + K(x_0 + s, y_0))$ and $\Psi_y(s) = (x_0, y_0 + s, z_0 + K(x_0, y_0 + s))$, but what do you mean by $(\Phi_x \circ \Psi_y)(x_0,y_0,z_0)$?

Comment: Surely it is the composition of the flows of the initial conditions. Should be clear from the context.